# Standard Deviation of a mean whose variables have their own uncertainty

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

So let's say I have some collection of variables $x_i$ each with their own uncertainty $\sigma_i$. (I'm trying to generalize this but if it helps, the $x_i$ themselves are a mean of other variables and $\sigma_i$ are the standard deviations of those means.)

Now I want to take the mean of these $x_i$ and compute the standard deviation on this mean. But I don't know how I should go about including the existing uncertainty in this calculation. My instinct says to just compute the propagated uncertainty of the mean and the standard deviation of the mean separately and then add those in quadrature, but I'm not sure if that's right.

Answer (score 2):

So you want the standard deviation of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i ?$

I'll presume you intend that the $x_i$ are independent (though  it's still doable if they aren't). One can show that for independent (or more generally uncorrelated) $x_i$ that $\operatorname{Var}(\sum_i x_i) = \sum_i \operatorname{Var}(x_i).$ So you have $$ \operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i\right) = \frac{1}{n^2} \operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_i x_i\right) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_i\sigma^2_i$$

So the standard deviation is just the square root of this, which I believe matches your verbal description.

Comment: The problem with this is that if all $\sigma_i=0$ then the standard deviation is $0$ and thus doesn't incorporate the spread of the $x_i$.

Comment: @A-P I thought $\sigma_i$ *was* the spread of the $x_i.$ In fact you say exactly that these are the standard deviations of the $x_i$ and that they are the uncertainties in the $x_i.$ Please clarify.

Comment: @A-P you might want to write down an explicit model of what's going on. Random variables already have uncertainty, so what is this "existing uncertainty." Do you mean that each $x_i$ is a measurement of the same (random) quantity where each measurement has an independent error. So $x_i = x+ \epsilon_i$ where $x$ and the $\epsilon_i$ are independent random variables and the means of the epsilon are zero and the standard deviations are $\sigma_i$?

Comment: Hopefully this clarifies it, (i'm splitting this up into multiple comments because I exceeded the character limit)
 I am starting with a collection of $\{y_{i,j}\}_{i\in[1,N],j\in[1,M]}$ Each $x_i=\frac{1}{M}\sum_{j=1}^M y_{i,j}$ (i.e. the mean of the $y$'s). And each $\sigma_i=\sqrt{\frac{1}{M}\sum_{j=1}^M (y_{i,j}-x_i)^2}$. (i.e. the standard deviation on the mean)

Comment: So now I want to find the mean of all $x_i$ with $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i$. Finally I want to compute the standard deviation, call it $\sigma'$, on this mean. But as far as I know there seem to be two ways of doing this. I could say $\sigma'=\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i-\bar{x})^2}$. This would give the standard deviation of the spread, ignoring the uncertainties associated with $x_i$. Alternatively I could do what you suggested above which is just the result of propogating uncertainties through the function "mean."

Comment: I'm thinking I should be doing both, setting $\sigma^*=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^N \left(\frac{\sigma_i}{N}\right)^2}$, and then taking my final standard deviation to be $\sigma=\sqrt{\sigma'^2+\sigma^{*2}}$
(Done)

Comment: @A-P So $\sigma_i$ is a *measured* quantity? And you're estimating, not computing? Also what do you want your final answer to represent? Is there any reason  you aren't just doing $$\frac{1}{NM-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^M (y_{ij}-\bar x)^2 ?$$

Comment: @A-P Like are the $x_i$ a different thing for each $i$, not just a different measurement of the same thing? Like $x_1$ is the mean of the heights of $10$ men, $\sigma_1$ the std deviation, and $x_2$ is of $10$ women. And (for some reason) you want to report the average height of everyone in the sample with a standard error? (And you have forgotten somehow the original data and only have the summary statistics so you can't do as I said above). If this is on the wrong track sorry, I'm trying to understand what quantity you're going for here.

Comment: @A-P I think what you have probably makes sense since we can write (being sloppy with the $N-1$'s etc) $$ \frac{1}{NM} \sum_i\sum_j (y_{ij}-\bar x)^2 = \frac{1}{NM} \sum_i\sum_j ((y_{ij}-x_i) - (x_i-\bar x))^2\\ =\frac{1}{NM}\sum_i\sum_j (y_{ij}-x_i)^2 - 2(y_{ij}-x_i)(x_i-\bar x) + (x_i-\bar x)^2 \\= \frac{1}{N}\sum_i \sigma_i^2 + \frac{1}{N}\sum_i (x_i-\bar x)^2 $$

Comment: Yeah that's about it, each $i$ varies across one dimension while each $j$ varies across another. And I think your second comment makes a lot of sense. Thanks.